Why is the return type of my method inferred as `never`?
See code below StackBlitz
I can't figure out how to make typescript infer the return type correctly. It's supposed to be an object with a results property, but instead, it's never.
You can tell by the error in the 2nd argument that it's able to infer the parameters just fine, or it wouldn't complain about the string argument where a number is expected.
import { Client } from '@hubspot/api-client';

type GetReturnType<T> = T extends (...args: unknown[]) => Promise<infer U> ? U : never;
type GetParameters<T> = T extends (...args: infer U) => unknown ? U : never;

async function call<T extends 'crm', U extends keyof Client[T], V extends keyof Client[T][U], W extends keyof Client[T][U][V]>(
  method: [api: T, entity: U, apiSection: V, method: W],
  ...args: GetParameters<Client[T][U][V][W]>
): Promise<GetReturnType<Client[T][U][V][W]>> {
  [method, args]

  return undefined as any
}

const res = await call(
  ['crm', 'companies', 'basicApi', 'getPage'],
  'test', // correctly shows error because it should be number
  undefined,
  ['city'],
);

res.results; // res is `never`. I don't understand why.


Huh, it works fine if I change line 3 to ...args: any[], or completely remove that part. Makes no sense to me tbh

Please [edit] the code to be a [mre] without dependency on third-party libraries if possible (unless the question is about such libraries). It takes a long time to pull in the dependencies for @hubspot/api-client in my IDE and in the stackblitz link, and IntelliSense is also really slowed down until loading completes. It makes it quite difficult to look at something which could probably be demonstrated in two or three lines of self-contained code, such as shown in this playground link. Could you edit to make the change, assuming you agree it's the same problem?
